# button characteristic different on similar stacks

Tags: livecode

I am inheriting the maintenance of a few stacks.

I have two stacks called “AI Frames 5.0” and “Flex Frames 5.0”.  I thought the two stacks were nearly identical. Not the case. Option menu buttons are behaving differently between the two.   STACK properties between the two stacks are the same. BUTTON properties between the two stacks are different.

The button on “AI Frames 5.0” has a property inspector title of *button* “Lamps” and HAS the Menu Items list that can be updated.
The button on "Flex Frames 5.0" has a property inspector title of *card button* “Lamps” and does NOT contain the Menu Items list.

If I drag out an option menu button onto each of the stacks, the new buttons “Look” the same but their properties are not the same – one is a card button, one is a button. (Same thing happens for other field types dragged onto stack.)

When I look at the project browser the buttons are listed in the tree in different locations. (image of project browser is included [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6opi.png))

AI Frames 5.0
|_ AIFrmEst
  |_ Button1

Flex Frames 5.0
|_ FlxFrmEst
|_ Button1

Is there an explanation to all this?  My main problem is that I need to change the menu options for the button on the “Flex Frames” stack.  How can I get “Flex Frames” stack to be similar to the “AI Frames” stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if, from the Message Box, you do this:

```
set the text of btn "lamps" to "This"&cr&"That" -- replace with your desired list
```

Comment: Yes, setting the text of the menu field from scripts or message box works fine.  I would prefer to set this from the button properties.

Answer (score 0):

I recently updated some *very* old stacks (Rev2.something) and buttons were all listed as "card buttons" in the browser, and fields as "bkgnd fields". Cloning the stack brought everything back to normal, tho I don't know if it will fix the button style as you want.